# Why my servlet do not creates a new thread on a request?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a structure like below :

[image]

I then requested `main.java` multiple times, declared a variable and incremented it on each call, which reflects the old value. Am I follow the correct approach ? Why a new thread is not created every time?

Comment: A new request for each request that you make although a SINGLE servlet instance is shared between requests. To increment a variable you must declare it OUTSIDE of the request scope. (i.e in the Servlet init() method) an then increment it on each call to the servlet.

Comment: @Down-voter please feel free to add a comment and your views.If you require some code, or any more specifications please leave a comment.

Comment: @GilesThompson Is the new thread created every time on each request?Any as you said about resources, then it may conflict or create inconsistency for the resources of A,B,C Java files?

Comment: Depends on your servlet implementation. Typically tomcat will utilise a thread pool and allocate a new thread to service each request you make. All threads will however "see" the same servlet instance but will call the servlets get method with their own data since each thread has its own stack. Thus to make a variable visible to all threads you must declare it outside the scope of a method as I do in my answer; each thread will then be able to update that variable. Additionally, you may want to synchronise access to the variable to prevent corruption.

Comment: You can add the code to be explained better

Comment: code is added in my answer.

Comment: There's no evidence here about threads one way or the other. There's no real evidence of anything really.

Comment: @EJP not sure what your getting at here. Its WELL documented that servlets use a Thread-Per-Request model. If you need further clarification on this see the following book excerpt which clearly explains this concept: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=h147IhQ5mSwC&pg=PT1429&lpg=PT1429&dq=servlet+container+thread+per+request&source=bl&ots=h4mE-azzyD&sig=KcnXlBHAuo2exIyxk6IIlDxmzxg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCGoVChMIi9ak6_jWxgIVBpxyCh2OuQrK#v=onepage&q=servlet%20container%20thread%20per%20request&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable OUTSIDE a the get/post method scope, you will then be able to increment it on each call to the servlet. See below:

```
private int counter;

private Object lock;

public void init() throws ServletException{
  //init lock
  lock = new Object();
  // create variable 
  counter = 0;
}


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
  //increment your counter here
  synchronized(lock){
  counter++;
  }
  response.setContentType("text/html");

  // here you can actually return the counter to the browser.
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("<h1>" + counter + "</h1>"); 
}
```

Comment: The `counter` variable cannot be `synchronized`

Comment: You are quite right, I have updated my answer to reflect this; instead a lock is created on initialisation and then subsequently used to synchronise access to the shared counter variable.

Comment: I understand, but how these variables are actually designed for various requests ?Do the general implementation includes/have sync blocks?They do not have the copy of their own variables?

Comment: And its just opposite, I don't want variables to be shared.I thought each request carry its own variables.How come then they are inter faring ?

Comment: The same variable scope access rules that apply to standard java classes ALSO apply to Servlets; Servlets are merely classes that are executed by a servlet container like Tomcat.  Therefore variables created within the scope of a method (i.e like the request get/post methods) are thread private - each thread will have their own thread-local copy of that variable. Conversely Instance variables (like counter in my example) are SHARED between threads hence the reason why my example accesses the counter variable from within a synchronised block.

Comment: Im confused. If you do NOT want the variables to be shared then declare them from within the scope each request method. You will of course not be able to count the request in this case.

Comment: So in nut shell, if a Servlet is giving control to a standard Java class, I have to make sure the variable is that class are either local or Synchronized well. Am I getting it correctly ?

Comment: Yes thats correct.Servlets are not thread-safe by default. You can implement the SingleThreadModel interface in order to automatically ensure that only one thread at a time can access the Servlets underlying "service" method. However the standard multi-threaded servlet configuration is much more efficient.